# Copy snowflake task results into stage and download to csv

Tags: scheduled-tasks, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, file-format, stage

Basically I need to automate all of the below in a snowflake TASK

- Create/replace a csv file format and stage in Snowflake
- Run task query (which runs every few days to pulls some stats)
- Unload the query results each time it runs into the Stage csv
- Download the contents of the stage csv to a local file on my machine

What I can't get right is the COPY INTO stage, how do I unload the results of the task each time it is run, into the stage?

I don't know what to put in the FROM statement - TITANLOADSUCCESSVSFAIL is not recognized but this is the name of the TASK

```
COPY INTO @TitanLoadStage/unload/ FROM TITANLOADSUCCESSVSFAIL FILE_FORMAT = TitanLoadSevenDays
```

First time using stage, and downloading locally with SF so appreciate any advice on how to get this up and running!

Thanks,
Nick

Full Code:

```
-- create a csv file format 
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT TitanLoadSevenDays
    type = 'CSV'
    field_delimiter = '|';

--create a snowflake staging table using the csv 
CREATE OR REPLACE STAGE TitanLoadStage
file_format = TitanLoadSevenDays;   
    
    
CREATE TASK IF NOT EXISTS TitanLoadSuccessVsFail
    WAREHOUSE = ITSM_LWH
     SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 1 * * * * Australia/Canberra' --every minute for testing purposes 
     COMMENT = 'Last 7 days of Titan game success vs fail load %'
AS
    WITH    SUCCESSCTE AS (
SELECT  CLIENTNAME
,       COUNT(EVENTTYPE) AS SuccessLoad --count success load events for that game 
FROM    vw_fact_gameload60
WHERE   EVENTTYPE = 103 --success load events
    AND     USERTYPE = 1 --real users
    AND     APPID = 2 --titan games
    AND     EVENTARRIVALDATE >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) --only looking at the last week  
GROUP BY CLIENTNAME
),

        FAILCTE AS ( --same as above but for failed loads
SELECT  CLIENTNAME
,       COUNT(EVENTTYPE) AS FailedLoads -- count failed load events for that game
FROM    vw_fact_gameload60
WHERE   EVENTTYPE = 106 -- failed load events 
    AND     USERTYPE = 1 -- real users 
    AND     APPID = 2 -- Titan games
    AND     EVENTARRIVALDATE >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) -- last 7 days 
  --AND     FACTEVENTARRIVALDATE BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())AND GETDATE() -- last 7 days 
GROUP BY CLIENTNAME
)
SELECT  COALESCE(s.CLIENTNAME, f.CLIENTNAME) AS ClientName
,       ZEROIFNULL(s.SuccessLoad) + ZEROIFNULL(f.FailedLoads) AS TotalLoads --sum the success and failed loads found for 103, 106 events only, calculated in CTEs
,       ZEROIFNULL(s.SuccessLoad) AS Cnt_SuccessLoad --count from success cte
,       ZEROIFNULL(f.FailedLoads) AS Cnt_FailedLoads --count from fail cte
,       CONCAT(ZEROIFNULL(ROUND(s.SuccessLoad * 100.0 / TotalLoads,2)) , '%') As Pct_Success --percentage of SuccessLoads against total
,       CONCAT(ZEROIFNULL(ROUND(f.FailedLoads * 100.0 / TotalLoads,2)), '%') AS Pct_Fail---percentage of failedLoads against total
FROM    SUCCESSCTE s 
FULL OUTER JOIN FAILCTE f -- outer join in the fail CTE by game name, outer required because some titan games sucess or fail events are NULL  
            ON  s.CLIENTNAME = f.Clientname
ORDER BY CLIENTNAME ASC



--copy the results from the query to the snowflake staging table created above 
COPY INTO @TitanLoadStage/unload/ FROM TITANLOADSUCCESSVSFAIL FILE_FORMAT = TitanLoadSevenDays


-- export the stage data to csv located in common folder 
GET @TitanLoadStage/unload/data_0_0_0.csv.gz file:\\itsm\group\ITS%20Management\Common\All%20Staff\SMD\Games\Snowflake%20and%20GamesDNA\Snowflake\SnowflakeCSV\TitanLoad.csv 


-- start the task 
ALTER TASK IF EXISTS TitanLoadSuccessVsFail RESUME
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the results of a query ran through a task, you need to materialize the results of said query to a table.

What you have now:

```sql
CREATE TASK mytask_minute
  WAREHOUSE = mywh
  SCHEDULE = '5 MINUTE'
AS
SELECT 1 x;

COPY INTO @TitanLoadStage/unload/
FROM mytask_minute;
```

(`mytask_minute` is not a table, so you can't select from it)

What you should do instead:

```sql
CREATE TASK mytask_minute
  WAREHOUSE = mywh
  SCHEDULE = '5 MINUTE'
AS
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE task_results_table
AS
SELECT 1 x;

COPY INTO @TitanLoadStage/unload/
SELECT *
FROM task_results_table;
```

Comment: If you want to automate all the activities you've listed then you either need to create a task for each one and link the tasks, or create a Stored Proc that executes these activities and use a task to run the SP